# How to install ta-lib in windows 11?

Tags: python, ta-lib

I used below python command

pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/masdeseiscaracteres/simple ta-lib

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ta-lib (from versions: none)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/windows.html) on your Windows 11 machine and run `conda install -c conda-forge ta-lib`

> NOTE : You may have to set conda on your system variables if the command conda is not working.

Comment: Conda is only compatible with python3 versions < 3.9 at the moment, which is a big step back.